# Android Google Play notification does not bring user to game screen

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-play-games

Similar questions to this have been trivial at best for answers.  I am using a faily up-to-date Google Play Game Services apk `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'` and I have `onInvitationReceived()` and `onConnected()` implemented.

However, `onInvitationReceived()` doesn't seem to be called when the invitee accepts the game invite in-game. And while I'm fairly certain onConnected() is called no matter what when the player connects via callback after `mGoogleClient.connect()` , it seems like the invitation is dropped or something because the player is not redirected to the game screen as I specified if the Bundle contains an invitation (I'm assuming this is called when the app is closed but either way, only a status bar notification is shown for the invite).

Any insight into this would be appreciated.  Here are the relevant methods:

onConnected() is from a class, that extends AndroidGame, and AndroidGame extends Activity (I've tried it in both classes, now I just have it overridden in the child class of AndroidGame):

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    // Connected to Google Play services!
    // The good stuff goes here.
    Games.Invitations.registerInvitationListener(mGoogleClient, Network.getInstance().mListener);

    if (connectionHint != null) {
        Invitation inv =
                connectionHint.getParcelable(Multiplayer.EXTRA_INVITATION);

        if (inv != null) {
            // accept invitation
            RoomConfig.Builder roomConfigBuilder = RoomConfig.builder(Network.getInstance());
            roomConfigBuilder.setMessageReceivedListener(Network.getInstance());
            roomConfigBuilder.setRoomStatusUpdateListener(Network.getInstance());
            roomConfigBuilder.setInvitationIdToAccept(inv.getInvitationId());
            RoomConfig roomConfig = roomConfigBuilder.build();
            Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.join(mGoogleClient, roomConfig);

            // prevent screen from sleeping during handshake
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

            // go to game screen
            setScreen(new CharSelectScreen(this));
        }
    }
}
```

onInvitationReceived is from my Network class, which is basically a singleton which handles other listeners as well.  onInvitationReceived() is both overridden in the Network class and in the anonymous inner class, just to cover my assets:

```
@Override
    public void onInvitationReceived(Invitation invitation) {
        Intent intent = Games.Invitations.getInvitationInboxIntent(game.getGoogleClient());
        game.startActivityForResult(intent, RC_INVITATION_INBOX);

        mIncomingInvitationId = invitation.getInvitationId();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(game.getApplicationContext());
        builder.setMessage("Join Game?")
                .setTitle("Bit Game Invitation!");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Join", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                if(!game.getGoogleClient().isConnected()) {
                    game.getGoogleClient().connect();
                }
                // User clicked OK button
                Bundle am = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(1, 3, 0);
                RoomConfig.Builder roomConfigBuilder = RoomConfig.builder(Network.getInstance());
                roomConfigBuilder.setMessageReceivedListener(Network.getInstance());
                roomConfigBuilder.setRoomStatusUpdateListener(Network.getInstance());
                roomConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(am);
                roomConfigBuilder.setInvitationIdToAccept(mIncomingInvitationId);
                RoomConfig roomConfig = roomConfigBuilder.build();
                Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.join(game.getGoogleClient(), roomConfig);

                // prevent screen from sleeping during handshake
                game.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
                dialog.dismiss();

                // go to game screen
                game.setScreen(new CharSelectScreen(game));
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // User cancelled the dialog
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
```

Comment: "If the signed-in player accepts an invitation from the notification area on the Android status bar, your game should accept the invitation and go directly to the game screen (skipping the main menu)."  As you can see both methods go to the Character Select screen (CharSelectScreen), but it doesn't appear anything but the app is being started.  Do I need to specify something in onCreate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, with the short answer being I did not follow the [Android Realtime Multiplayer](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer) recipe (guidelines) as closely as I should have.

The guidelines calls for easy access to Google Play sign-in, either automatically when starting the app or I'd imagine preferably, a button to sign in.  When I added this, my callback `onConnected()` code worked, the invitation allowed the user to proceed to the designated game screen with a default waiting room pop-up (implementation shown [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer#handling_invitations)).  I am still debugging the `onInvitationReceived()` callback, but I suspect that when the invitation is received when the game is open, the game crash means there is something wrong with my implementation.

All in all, I think it was a bit of misunderstanding on my end, the documentation is fairly intuitive.  Thank you for helping, and I hope this will help future Google Play Game Services developers.